1TB Samsung M.2 SSD drive (less than 2 years old) just died after the recent storms. Now it will not post. What can be done?
I have a 1TB Samsung M.2 SSD drive in my machine. It serves as my c drive Windows 11 OS. It's less than 2 years old. After the recent storms in Dallas it suddenly will not even post!
We eliminated all other parts from causing the problem. After installing an old Windows 10 M.2 disk and was able to boot as normal.

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post ... I have a dead drive is not a question
